# How to create chess auto-match maker with websocket-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I would like to make a Rails chess app using websockets where it automatically matches players of similar skill.

With Rails the typical setup consists of multiple backend Rails processes each of which is essentially stateless inbetween requests. Morever, typically the multiple backends do not directly communicate with each other.

If many players have websocket connections to different backends how would an auto-match maker work? An auto-match maker looks at all the players wanting to play and matches them up appropriately. This would seem to be a stateful centralized algorithm going against the grain of multiple independent backend Rails processes.

Given those two conflicting aspects, is there an advisable idiomatic way of making an auto-match maker in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really done stuff like this but I might be able to point you in the right direction:

You should take a look into [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use), redis and [socket.io-cluster](https://github.com/muchmala/socket.io-cluster)

I found a [slideshow](https://speakerdeck.com/conferencesbox/socket-dot-io-in-chess-realtime-multiplayer-web-application), maybe you can get into touch with the author.

Comment: That slideshow seems to be focused on websocket like communication rather than how to implement a centralized match maker in Rails.